# How to pass url as @PathVariable to spring RestController?

Tags: java, spring, rest, get

I want to put URL in GET Request so I can then redirect the user to the given URL.

This is my code so far:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/mapping/{param1}/{redirectLink}" }, method = { RequestMethod.GET})
public void mapping(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable("param1") String param1, @PathVariable("redirectLink") String redirectLink) throws IOException {
    // code i wanna run
    response.sendRedirect(backLink);
}
```

Example url i use to GET - http://localhost:8080/app/controller/redirectionTest/1234/http://localhost:3000/main

So when I call the GET method I wanna run some code then be redirected to http://localhost:3000/main but the URL has slashes in it so it makes it impossible.

Comment: Why don't you use a Query Parameter instead?

Comment: Any way is fine as long as you explain me how to do it preferably with an example.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the slashes with the standard code: `%2F`.

http://localhost:8080/app/controller/redirectionTest/1234/http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fmain

I have replaced the colons with `%3A` just in case you have a problem with that one also

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Ok will try that tomorrow

Answer (score -2):

You can try this

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/mapping/{param1}" }, method = { RequestMethod.GET})
public void mapping(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable("param1") String param1, @RequestParam(required = true, value = "redirectLink") String redirectLink) throws IOException {
    // code i wanna run
    response.sendRedirect(redirectLink);
}
```

Now, visit http://localhost:8080/app/controller/redirectionTest/1234?redirectLink=http://localhost:3000/main